# max and min of $f(x,y)=(x+y){e^{-y^2+x}}$

Tags: real-analysis

I want calculate max and min of f on V=$\{(x,y)\in R^2: x^2+2xy+y^2-2x-2y+1=0\}$

f  $\in C(R^2)$ and V is a compact (it's a parable?)

so for Weierstrass do absolute max and min exists?

Can i use Lagrange's multipliers?

Comment: Notice that $x^2+2xy+y^2-2x-2y+1=(x+y-1)^2$

Answer (score 2):

Since $x^2+2xy+y^2-2x-2y+1=(x+y-1)^2=0$, you simply have $x+y=1$ and thus $f(x,y)=e^{-y^2+1-y}$ on $V$. Since $-y^2+1-y=5/4-(y+1/2)^2$, the range of $f$ on $V$ is obvious.

Comment: $f(x,y)=e^{-y^2+1-y}$ on V so I have a max in $(3/2,-1/2)$?

Comment: there is an error in the text

Answer (score 1):

> and V is a compact (it's a parable?)

**Hint**; note for $V$:
$$x^2+2xy+y^2-2x-2y+1=0 \iff \left( x+y-1 \right)^2=0$$